# iframe with srcdoc: same-page links load the parent page in the frame

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink, href

Same-page links work by referencing another element that has `id="sec-id"` on the same page, using

```
<a href="#sec-id"></a>
```

for instance. A link like this is relative.

However, if I use that very same syntax in the iframe in my LaTeX.js playground, it will not just scroll to the destination element, but (re)load the whole playground page inside the ifame. (Note that I set the contents of the iframe programmatically with `iframe.srcdoc = html`)

Example: [LaTeX.js playground](https://latex.js.org/playground.html), right at the end of the first section click on the link in "See also Sec­tion 11." in the iframe on the right side.

What could be the reason?

**UPDATE**: I now understand the source of the problem: the browser uses the document's base URL to make all relative URLs absolute (see [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)). The trouble starts with an iframe that has its content set with `srcdoc`: no unique base URL is specified, and in that case the base URL of the parent frame/document is used--the playground in my case (see the [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/urls-and-fetching.html#terminology-2)).

Therefore, the question becomes: is there a way to reference the `srcdoc` iframe in a base URL? or is it possible to make the browser *not* prepend the base? or to make a base URL that doesn't change the relative `#sec-id` URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about catching the event and scrolling to the desired anchor?

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    $('.iframe').animate({
       scrollTop: $(e.target.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Brilliant idea! I don't think your code is correct, though: it should run inside the iframe, right? So why the `$('.iframe')`?

Comment: Also, another nitpick ;-) Not every `<a>` should be chosen, only those with an `href` that starts with `#`--but I can easily fix this one, the idea is what counts.

Comment: Great to hear, the $('.iframe') is the element to scroll, so that is why it is selected.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly how you could resolve this, I think it is because the `srcdoc`, you can't use the `src` with the content-type because the character limit, but you can convert it to a `Blob` and it kinda works, the style are lost though. Maybe you can use it as a starting point, based on your page:

```
// Get the document content
const doc = document.querySelector('iframe').srcdoc;
// Convert it to blob
const blob = new Blob([doc], {type : 'text/html'});
// Load the blob on the src attr
document.querySelector('iframe').src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
// Remove srcdoc to allow src
document.querySelector('iframe').removeAttribute('srcdoc');
```

Comment: This may actually become a good workaround by circumventing the `srcdoc` problem. But I first have to figure out how fix the broken styles...

Comment: Yeah, it is a tricky one, I would try to assign the styles after loading the content with javascript, but I don't know if you can do it. Good luck.

Comment: Also, this solution has one more drawback: it is quite easy to only use absolute paths to fix the styles, but if I use the playground locally for testing, those paths are `file:///...` paths, and they are not allowed with Blobs or `iframe.src`. So I'm going to go with the other workaround.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, it seems that my question is not possible, i.e., it is not possible to use relative same-page links in an iframe that has its content set using `srcdoc`. A workaround has to be used, see the other answer.